# How could I refactor this "nearly" duplicate code with a query, when only three characters differ between methods?

Tags: methods, refactoring, duplicates

I'm thinking an enum might be the way to go, and depending on the action (create, delete) it replaces the characters? Then I'd have to store a variable for "--", "++", ">=" and ">" hrrmm. Any simple suggestions would be great, and I could use it as a future reference as to how I might tackle a problem like this!

```cs
public void ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnCreate(Category category)
{
    var tx = _session.BeginTransaction();
    var categories = _session.QueryOver<Category>()
        .Where(c => c.Parent.Id == category.Parent.Id && c.OrderInList >= category.OrderInList) // the >= category.OrderInList here
        .List<Category>();

    foreach(var item in categories)
    {
        item.OrderInList++; // The ++ here.
        _session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
    }
    tx.Commit();
}

public void ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnDelete(Category category)
{
    var tx = _session.BeginTransaction();
    var categories = _session.QueryOver<Category>()
        .Where(c => c.Parent.Id == category.Parent.Id && c.OrderInList > category.OrderInList) // the > category.OrderInList here
        .List<Category>();

    foreach(var item in categories)
    {
        item.OrderInList--; // the -- here.
        _session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
    }
    tx.Commit();
}
```

**Edit 1**

> Could not determine member type from Invoke, Invoke(value(CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.DataServices.CategoryDataServices+<>c_*DisplayClass8).orderComparer, c.OrderInList, value(CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.DataServices.CategoryDataServices+<>c*_DisplayClass8).category.OrderInList), System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression

**Trace:**

> [Exception: Could not determine member type from Invoke, Invoke(value(CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.DataServices.CategoryDataServices+<>c_*DisplayClass8).orderComparer, c.OrderInList, value(CumbriaMD.Infrastructure.DataServices.CategoryDataServices+<>c*_DisplayClass8).category.OrderInList), System.Linq.Expressions.InvocationExpression]
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessBooleanExpression(Expression expression) +1113
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression expression) +114
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessAndExpression(BinaryExpression expression) +85
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression) +124
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression expression) +95
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessLambdaExpression(LambdaExpression expression) +52
>      NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessExpression(Expression`1 expression) +39
>      NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Add(Expression`1 expression) +107
>      NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.Where(Expression`1 expression) +42
>      NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2.NHibernate.IQueryOver.Where(Expression`1 expression) +42

Comment: Hmmm for some reason it isn't syntax highlighting?

Comment: Added syntax highlighting, for future reference you can tell it what language to use using `<!-- language: c# -->`.

Comment: Thanks :) will remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to start would be to just break out the common functionality using a `Func` for the difference and get rid of most of the duplication.

```cs
public void ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnCreate(Category category)
{
    ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnAction(category, (a,b) => a>=b, x => x + 1);
}

public void ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnDelete(Category category)
{
    ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnAction(category, (a,b) => a>b, x => x - 1);
}

public void ArrangeCategoriesOrderOnAction(Category category, 
                               Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> orderComparer,
                               Func<int, int> orderUpdateCalculator)
{
    var tx = _session.BeginTransaction();
    var categories = _session.QueryOver<Category>()
        .Where(c => c.Parent.Id == category.Parent.Id 
               && orderComparer(c.OrderInList, category.OrderInList))
        .List<Category>();

    foreach (var item in categories)
    {
        item.OrderInList = orderUpdateCalculator(item.OrderInList);
        _session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
    }
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, trying to understand a bit whats going on. One thing I notice though is that the ArrangeCategoriesOnAction doesn't have a way to swap the greater than symbol in the query depending on whether its a create (greater than or equal to) or a delete (greater than) - but you might not have seen that because it didn't highlight the syntax! Looks much much cleaner though.

Comment: @CraigWhitley Ah, no, didn't see that difference. You could solve that using another `Func` that takes two integers, compares them in the way you want and returns a boolean and pass one "compareFunc" and one "actionFunc" to the method.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this is really helpful. Still quite new and Ive never noticed myself *knowingly* using Func, so I'll have a good read about it - looks very useful.

Comment: Ah brilliant, cheers again. This compiles anyways, it *is* a bit hard to understand at first - but I have the trusty pencil and paper out to try and figure it out! TIL :)

Comment: I've edited my original post with an error that's thrown when I try to run your edits hrrrm. Still working out whats going on, but yeah!

Comment: @CraigWhitley Sorry, too little coffee in the morning :) To participate in Linq queries (other than in-memory), a `Func` needs to be wrapped in an `Expression` to work. Same usage from the other function, just some extra wrapping on the function parameter. The most important takeaway isn't the syntax, it's that you can pass functions (lambdas or normal functions) to a method and use that there. Quite useful for refactoring.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I think I've seen the Expression<Func<>> markup in repositories and whatnot. Cheers for the update - I understand whats going on now (page of A4 scribbling later). Much appreciated & problem solved :)

Comment: After posting the question separately I can't seem to get a response, so I humbly return and wonder if you could take a look at it for me? While I understand what's going on here, I can't compile it because it's trying to treat the orderComparer as a method? I've literally been struggling with this for the past 3 hours sorry. Questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913562/error-method-delegate-or-event-expected-when-using-an-expression-inside-an-n - I'd love any help you might be able to give thanks.